# Mac OSX 10.9 Software for Changing Aspect Ratio of Image

Tags: osx, images, image-editor

I would like to adjust the aspect ratio of a rather large (3300 x 2550) .jpg image. The image is set on a black background, and all I would like to do is add more black space on the left and right sides of the image.

I think I could probably accomplish this in Keynote (which I do have installed) but I thought I would ask here first since most of my image editing experience is somewhat amateurish.

Does anyone know of any (free) software for Mavericks that could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try one or the other of these options ...

- GraphicConverter. It is not free. But when you plan to do this or anything else with images more than once, and you need an awfully damn good tool, this is it.
- Open the image in NeoOffice (free) and fudge adding a border around it.
- Find a free image editing software with a search using your favorite Web engine. Photoscape X seems to be one at the top of my list.